# Получение JSON с сайта с авторизацией

Tags: python, json

Предположим, я могу получить некоторый JSON-объект с сайта командой `curl -i -X GET 'https://api.iot.yandex.net/v1.0/user/info' -H 'Authorization: Bearer MY_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN'` при помощи консоли. Как я могу получить это значение, а затем преобразовать его в словарь при помощи Python-скрипта?

Comment: Достаточно просто запрограммировать. Перед тем как задавать вопросы: "а как сделать?" лучше стоило погуглить. Используйте библиотеку requests для совершения запроса на сервер и json что бы превратить полученные данные в словарь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://api.iot.yandex.net/v1.0/user/info'
TOKEN = '481814381843814' # MY_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {TOKEN}'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
json_res = json.loads(r.text)
```

В следующий раз прошу вас хотя бы попытаться поискать информацию самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ получен с помощью https://curlconverter.com/

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer MY_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN',
}

response = requests.get('https://api.iot.yandex.net/v1.0/user/info', headers=headers)
```